# Is it possible to do standard TLS hankshave for Mutual Authentication in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, https, tls1.2

As I know, standard mutual authentication as bellow, this is standard TLS process.

> Mutual Authentication With mutual authentication, the server and the
>   client authenticate each other. Mutual authentication is of two types:
>   Certificate-based (see Figure 25–4) User name/password-based (see
>   Figure 25–5)

[Mutual Authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncbt/index.html)

**But I cannot see any related usage in firebase, is it possible to do standard TLS hankshave for Mutual Authentication in Firebase?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't customize those kinds of settings on Firebase - they just don't expose those kind of server settings for you (*the developer*) to mess with. You can't customize what version of TLS or any of that - it's all handled automatically.